# Circumvent the DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument event

Tags: javascript, html, dom, w3c, mutation-events

Assume I have a javascript function `createMyElement` which returns a node that can be inserted into an HTML document.

In order to function properly, the code of the node created by `createMyElement` has to listen for events on the global `document` at least as soon as it is inserted in the document.

My first attempt was to add `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument` and `DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument` listeners to the node at creation time that add and remove the needed listener on `document` in turn.

However, the mutation events are deprecated by now (and don't seem to work reliably across browsers), so I am looking for a better solution.

Adding the listener for events at `document` at the creation time of the node would work. However, this doesn't seem to be a good solution as it would create memory and performance leaks: Even after the node was being removed from the document again and not needed anymore, the listener (and its references to the node) on the `document` would still persist.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - why does the node created by `createMyElement` need to listen to events on document?  Event listening usually works the other way around.

Comment: My application generates custom events using the built-in event system. My idea was to dispatch these events on the document as they are really global events. E.g. if a global state changes, an event is dispatched. All nodes that use this state have to listen to this changed event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I originally asked my question, the substitute for mutation events, namely mutation observers as defined in http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#mutation-observers, have been implemented in a number of browsers.

So a simple answer to my own question is to simply use mutation observers on the document to listen for nodes to be inserted or removed.

An even better way, however, is to use the new custom elements from https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/spec/custom/index.html, which gives one `insertedCallback`s and `removedCallback`s for custom elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [series of function callbacks](https://github.com/caolan/async#series) or [on-demand script callbacks](http://www.phpied.com/async-javascript-callbacks/) to serialize the events.